# Return animation of shared element not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-jetpack

I have created a recyclerview in Fragment A and on click of a element it opens the second fragment, where the image from one oage to another should animate. The enter aniamtion is working fine, but the exit animation isn't working. The fragments are added with NavigationEditor.

This is the code :

RecyclerView fragment ->

```
public class SightSeeingFragment extends Fragment {

    RecyclerView sightSeeingRv;
    ArrayList<Place> placeArrayList;
    SightSeeingAdapter sightSeeingAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        postponeEnterTransition();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sight_seeing, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        postponeEnterTransition();
        init(view);
    }

    private void init(View view) {
        sightSeeingRv = view.findViewById(R.id.sight_seeing_rv);
        setRecyclerView();
    }

    private void setRecyclerView() {
        new SetRecyclerView().execute();
    }

    class SetRecyclerView extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
            sightSeeingRv.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            placeArrayList = new Gson().fromJson(placesToVisit,
                    new TypeToken<List<Place>>() {
                    }.getType());
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            if (sightSeeingAdapter == null)
                sightSeeingAdapter = new SightSeeingAdapter(getContext(), placeArrayList);
            sightSeeingRv.setAdapter(sightSeeingAdapter);
           sightSeeingRv.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreDraw() {
                startPostponedEnterTransition();
                return true;
            }
        });
        }
    }
}
```

Adapter ->

```
public class SightSeeingAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<Place> placeArrayList;
    public SightSeeingAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Place> placeArrayList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.placeArrayList = placeArrayList;
        if(this.placeArrayList == null)
            placeArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if(position == 0)
            return 0;
        else return 1;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if(viewType == 0)
        {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.sightseeing_row_0, parent, false);
            return new SightSeeingTextViewHolder(view);
        }else
        {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.row_sight_seeing, parent, false);
        return new SightSeeingViewHolder(view);
    }}

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if(position!=0) {
            ((SightSeeingViewHolder)holder).bindView(position-1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return placeArrayList.size()+1;
    }

    class SightSeeingTextViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public SightSeeingTextViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }
    }
    class SightSeeingViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        TextView nameOfPlace;
        TextView descOfPlace;
        ImageView imageOfPlace;
        CardView placeRow;
        int position;
        public SightSeeingViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            nameOfPlace = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name_of_place);
            descOfPlace = itemView.findViewById(R.id.desc_of_place);
            imageOfPlace = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_of_place);
            placeRow = itemView.findViewById(R.id.place_row);
        }

        public void bindView(int position) {
            Place place = placeArrayList.get(position);
            this.position = position;
            nameOfPlace.setText(place.getNameOfPlace());
            descOfPlace.setText(place.getShortDescription());
            placeRow.setTag(position);
            placeRow.setOnClickListener(this);
            Glide.with(context).load(Utils.getDrawableImage(place.getImage(),context)).into(imageOfPlace);
            ViewCompat.setTransitionName(imageOfPlace, position+"");
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int position = (int) view.getTag();
            FragmentNavigator.Extras extras = new FragmentNavigator.Extras.Builder()
                    .addSharedElement(imageOfPlace,position+"").build();
            Navigation.findNavController(view)
                    .navigate(SightSeeingFragmentDirections.actionNavigationSightseeingToPlaceholder()
                            .setPlaceDetail(placeArrayList.get(position)).setTransitionName(position+""),extras);
        }
    }
}
```

Fragment B ->

```
public class DetailOfPlaceFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    Place place;
    ImageView placeImage;
    TextView placeDetails;
    Button checkTheLocation;
    String transitionName;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        postponeEnterTransition();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            setSharedElementEnterTransition(TransitionInflater.from(getContext()).inflateTransition(android.R.transition.move));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail_of_place, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        place = DetailOfPlaceFragmentArgs.fromBundle(getArguments()).getPlaceDetail();
        transitionName = DetailOfPlaceFragmentArgs.fromBundle(getArguments()).getTransitionName();
        init(view);
    }

    private void init(View view) {
        placeImage = view.findViewById(R.id.place_image);
        placeDetails = view.findViewById(R.id.place_details);
        checkTheLocation = view.findViewById(R.id.check_the_location);
        checkTheLocation.setOnClickListener(this);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            placeImage.setTransitionName(transitionName);
        }
        Glide.with(getContext()).load(Utils.getDrawableImage(place.getImage(),getContext())).listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                startPostponedEnterTransition();
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                startPostponedEnterTransition();
                return false;
            }
        }).into(placeImage);
        placeDetails.setText(place.getDescription());
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        String url = String.format(getString(R.string.maps_url),place.getLatOnMap()+"",
                place.getLondOnMap()+"",place.getNameOfPlace());
        Utils.openActionIntent(url,getContext());
    }
}
```

Also the enter animation isn't much fluid due to the postpone animation. But that is a secondary concern.

Answer (score 2):

Your RecyclerView fragment needs to also use `postponeEnterTransition()` and `startPostponedEnterTransition()`: its view is going to be destroyed when it is put on the back stack and without postponing the transition, the shared element transition will attempt to happen before your `AsyncTask` actually completes that the `RecyclerView` is repopulated with data, leading to there being no View to return to.

The [pull request that added shared element transitions to the GithubBrowserSample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/pull/546) is a good place to start when looking for what all the moving pieces that need to be changed are.

Comment: As suggested made the changes in the RecyclerView fragment code. Have a look at it. As it still does not work.

Comment: @ParthAnjaria - your `startPostponedEnterTransition()` is one frame too early - it hasn't actually laid out any of the RecyclerView items. See the `addOnPreDrawListener` section of the pull request I linked to (you aren't using Kotlin and the helper extension, so you'll need to add an observer and remove it after the first callback though)

Comment: made the change as shown in the pull request. but still not working.

Comment: also cant get the return transition to work. any more ideas @ianhanniballake